# Same height for nav tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a bootstrap tabs, and some of them have very long text, and it creates ugly space between tabs and content. How can I set the other tabs to have the same size as the biggest one?

[image]

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-wifi"/> Not that long</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"/> Something really really really long</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"/> Not that long</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#" class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-star"/> Not that long</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Equal height columns with flexbox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276

Comment: That is not working for me, if I use flex on ul, tabs design becomes mess.

Comment: Can you post the CSS you're working with? Will help if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Find justified nav tabs exmaple on page, and just edit the nav tab content to something longer.
http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto-admin/1.5.1/ui-elements-tabs.html

Comment: @Michael_B I found a solution. Thank you, you were very helpfull.

Comment: I was one step away. Just needed to add flex properties to `<a>`. I'm glad you found your solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found a solution!

```
<style>
.nav-tabs{
    display: flex;
}
.nav-tabs li {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

.nav-tabs li  a {
    flex: 1;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Nice work. We were doing the same thing in parallel. Except `flex: 1` on the `a` wasn't working for me in dev tools so I was stuck on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make them all taller or you can shorten the name of the tab that's too long. Tab names shouldn't really be very long anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use flexbox (which is not supported by older browsers), your only choice is to set all the tabs as tall as the tallest one explicitly with a pixel height. Flexbox is a great and sadly not yet fully usable solution to this kind of problem. Without it, there's no flexible way to accomplish this.

Comment: Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, except IE 8 & 9. See the [browser support tables](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). 
Also, if flexbox isn't an option, there are table properties.

Comment: You're right, I haven't looked at those tables in a while, but in the world of client work, the spotty support for IE 10 & 11, and the lack of it for old IE and old android makes it not an option for me. I totally agree with your comment though that it is the solution.

Comment: I can use flexbox, but I can not make it work. Can you post a solution ?

Comment: I just adapted the jsfiddle that was inside the stackoverflow answer in the comment on your original post. http://jsfiddle.net/ingridly/yuwqsrab/12/. I had to change your <i> elements to spans because they were being read as a containing tag (like `<em>`) and jsfiddle was barfing. That could also be an issue for you. Here's some opinions on using the `<i>` element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span